# Python for loop generates list?

Tags: python, list

```
a = [0,1]+[2 for _ in range (10**7+1)]
```

I'm wondering what this code in Python 3 does? I tried printing the list a but it took way too long...I'm really asking about the second part. I'm confused about the underscore there.

Comment: `_` is just a variable name like any other. They could have called it `i` or `wilco` or `michaeljordan`.

Comment: `[2 for _ in range (10**7 + 1)]` is giving you a list which has length 10**7+1 which the elements are all 2

Comment: this appends 10**7+1 2s to `[0,1]`

Comment: just try it with a smaller range and you will see

Comment: This can be rewritten as: `[0,1] + ([2] * (10**7+1))`

Comment: That's [0, 1, 2, 2 ...]

Comment: While all other comments are correct, to answer your question: the underscore is simply a variable name. It is a Python convention to use `_` for superfluous or unused variables, which is the case here (it is only used as the "counter" for the iteration and its actual value is not used)

Comment: The `_` is just a conventional name in Python for a loop variable that you don't intend to use. You could use `i` instead. `[2 for i in range(n)]` is an inefficient way to create a list of `n` 2s. The sensible way is `[2]*n`

Comment: I suggest you change the number in the range statement to something very small, and see what it does. It will be much easier to figure out from there.

Comment: it creates new list with combining two list ,first list [0,1] second list generated from [2 for _ in range (10**7+1)].Second list size 10000001 therefore printing list too long..

Comment: I see, it's just _ isn't really a good variable name for something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the expression is called *list comprehension*. Its used to create a new list as you iterate another list/iterable. A good scenario is

```
[value for item in range(integer)]
```

New array is generated `[]`, the values of that array will depend on the `value` from the expression above on each iteration . Meaning if you do something line

```
[x for x in range(3)] # returns [0,1,2]
[x*4 for x in range(2)] # returns [0,4,8]
```

In such cases value can be an expression or a constant
In your case `[2 for x in range(3)] # returns [2,2,2]` because of each iteration the the value remains 2

I almost forget `[a,b] + [c,d,e] = [a,b,c,d,e]`

So to make it simple `[0,1] + [2 for x in range(3)] # returns [0,1,2,2,2]`

Lastly your range is too big that's why its taking too long as mentioned in the comments!